# How to remove right padding/margin/space from a custom bar button item which has an image?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for the past two days and still nothing I have tried works for me. Some solutions I have tried either stretch or completely mess up my custom image but nothing removes the right padding. Here is my code below as well as the result. Notice how the right bar button has a bigger space than the left system one.

[image]

```
    var saveButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32))
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: "saveAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    let img = UIImage(named: "save")
    saveButton.setBackgroundImage(img, forState: .Normal)
    var saveBarButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: saveButton)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(saveBarButton, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright guys, I've found a solution that works pretty well for me. Instead of creating and setting the bar button item in code I added one in storyboard and set it's left margin in size inspector to -6 (or whatever value you like) and it's right margin to 6 (again whatever value you prefer ***note that the two values must be the same values but one is positive and the other is negative***). Then I set it's image to the image I desired in the attributes inspector. If for some reason you want to change the image in code you can do so like this:

```
barButtonOutlet.image = UIIMage(named: "yourImage") as UIImage?
```

Hope this helps some of you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.  Try..

```
rightBtn.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -13.0, bottom: 0, right: 13.0)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn
```